# Chaning the cursor from “wait” to “auto” while the jquery performs a function

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

I have a jQuery function that  generate QR codes and feeds these into an empty IMG tag. the code works perfectly, the only problem is that it takes several seconds to generate this code. So, I basically need the cursor to show a busy sign while the function is executing and to return to normal  once the generated code has been fed into the empty img tag complete.

My problem is two fold.

Question 1

I am unable to get the mouse to change to a busy sign. I tried using the following CSS code to no avail:

```
$('body').css({'cursor':'wait'});
```

Question 2

How do I get the code to know when the QR code has been created and to then return the browser to normal? I suspect that the best way around that would be to run a check to see when the image tag has been fed the values and to then return the cursor to normal.

I have enclosed my code below:

**the empty image tag:**

```
<img id="qr-code-image"  src="" style="vertical-align: middle" />
```

**The jQuery function:**

```
 $('#link-types input[type=radio]').click(function() {
  $('#qr-code-image').attr('src', '');
 });

  $('#link-types input[type=radio]').click(function() {

  if (!$("input[class='link-selector-bespoke']").is(':checked')) {
   var url = $('#link-flash').text();
   $('body').css({'cursor':'wait'});
  }
  else
  {
   var url = $('#link-bespoke').text();
  }         
  var encodedvalues  = jQuery.base64Encode(url);

  var imgUrl = '<?= $this->baseUrl() ?>/scripts/qr/t/' + encodedvalues;

 $('#qr-code-image').attr('src', imgUrl);
  $('body').css({'cursor':'default'});
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the onload event callback function of the image:

```
$('#qr-code-image').off('load').on('load',function(){
     if(this.complete)
          $('body').css({cursor:'default'});
}).attr('src', imgUrl);
```

Comment: Hello roasted. thank you so much for your answer. its totally correct